# symfony2 on/offline web application

Tags: symfony, local-storage, offlineapps, offline-mode, offline-browsing

Im looking for the best way to build an on/offline application with symfony2. I need some advice here:

- Users can access the application from navigator on their computer or from tablet (like iPad)
- When there is no connection the application must run in offline mode
- Data should be stored locally until the detection of a connection
- Local data must be syncronized with server data

the question is : what is the best approach to implement this behavior knowing that the application must be developed with symfony2 (normal behavior).The main problem is the offline mode. Should i use HTML5 local storage or SQLite?
and what is the best approach to syncronize data between the two modes (from server to local/or from local to server)

Comment: Maybe you should consider a [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/)/CouchDB implementation! When you write an app with consideration for an "offline mode", you will have to maintain a lot or all of the functionality on the front-end. The back-end becomes much more "dumb" with just simple CRUD functionality. There's a lot of ways to go about this, Symfony2 being one solution.. but your question is too broad. Sorry.

Comment: I think that CoucheDB can help me in managing conflicts easly. Correct me if i'm wrong, but if i write all of the functionality  on the front-end where is the point of using symfony here ? im just looking for answers .Can you explain a little bit how symfony can help me in this aproach ?

Comment: That's why I said Symfony2 is only _one_ solution. In your scenario, you're turning it into a CRUD interface, really. Sorry - you have to be more specific around here. You don't even mention what kind of application you're doing. It is the vaguest thing to ask.

Comment: To be more clear my application have to manage product stock so it includs CRUD , listing of available products ,managing clients and showing some statics related to each client. The access to the application must be secured. So for exemple how user can navigate between pages if there is no connection ?

Comment: AngularJS is one front-end MVC that has support for "pages" without having to make an HTTP request. I would look into that as well.